# my query rss didn't work

Tags: xml, rss, feed

anyone can help me? my rss feed doesnt work, the error is like this

An error occurred while trying to validate this feed.

Possible causes:

- The address may be incorrect. Make sure the address is spelled
  correctly. Try loading the feed directly in your browser to make sure
  a feed exists at that address.
- The feed may be temporarily unavailable. The server may be down, or
  too slow. Try again later.
- The validator may be busted. If the feed exists, the server is fine,
  and the problem is reproducible, let us know on the
  feedvalidator-users mailing list.

please help me, i try in here http://validator.w3.org/feed

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. I don't see how any of us could suggest a fix for it given what we know about your feed.

Comment: @Quentin oh i'm sorry, here the feed http://portalkbr.com/index.xml i dont know why, in browser can work, but in validator is error

Comment: I can't make a connection to that server. "The server may be down, or too slow". Or you might have a network routing issue.

Comment: @Quentin hoo okay, thanks for the answer. but, i want to ask, is there any problem with my query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The domain your XML is on appears to be down, or inaccessible by the general population, which is why the validator is saying the XML feed is unavailable at http://portalkbr.com/index.xml